# Grouped bar chart not working with lattice in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm having trouble creating grouped barplots.  Have explored base graphics and lattice.

My data looks like

> compound detection LUtype
>   a  50         ag
>     a 75         urban
>       a         34         mixed
>       b         89         ag
>       ......

I'd like to create a plot with compounds on the y axis (horizontal bar plot) with the bars colored to represent the land use type and detection on the x axis.
These data are stored in a data frame, which I tried converting to a matrix with as.matrix, but this doesn't work and from what I can tell, the matrix is only the row of compounds. This does not produce a plot.

```
bars<-data.frame(data6$compound,data6$detection,data6$LUtype)  
barsM<-as.matrix(data6$compound,data6$detection,data6$LUtype)  
barplot(barsM,horiz=TRUE,beside=TRUE)
```

I also tried to bypass the matrix by using lattice, by no plot here either.

```
library(lattice)  
require(lattice)  
barchart(data6$detection~data6$compound,groups=data6$LUtype,bars)
```

I'm reading this article
[plotting grouped bar charts in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210152/plotting-grouped-bar-charts-in-r), and I have basically the same set up, but these solutions aren't working for me.

Comment: Please add data, and show (not with a link to an article) what code you tried and what did not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, I usually input large datasets as .txt files but I created some data here for an example.   `Data<-data.frame(pesticide=rep(c("a","b","c","d"),each=3),LU=rep(c("ag","urb","mixed"),4),detection=c(10,50,85,74,12,61,95,45,12,72,65,42))  
write.table(Data,file="Data.txt",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)  

pdf("testcode.pdf",width=11,height=8.5)  
require(lattice)  
barchart(detection~pesticide,groups=LU,Data,auto.key=list(columns=4))  
dev.off()`  I don't get an errors using this code but no plot is generated.  I'm using the most recent version of R.

Comment: Below code made an example data pdf  in my environment. `require(lattice) 
Data<-data.frame(pesticide=rep(c("a","b","c","d"),each=3), LU=rep(c("ag","urb","mixed"),4),  detection=c(10,50,85,74,12,61,95,45,12,72,65,42)) 
write.table(Data,file="Data.txt",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE) 
d <- read.delim("Data.txt")
pdf("testcode.pdf",width=11,height=8.5) 
barchart(pesticide ~ detection, groups=LU, d, auto.key=list(columns=3)) 
dev.off() `